# Map reduce a particular region data from hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to Hadoop and Hbase. I would like to know if there is a way I can Map reduce on some selected regions of data in hbase table. I mean Is there a way I can specify which regions of the table the Map reduce should take instead of taking the complete table and splitting the tasks on the basis of the number of regions. Some code snippet will be of great help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set start row and end row of your processing. If you doing it once - you can get start and stop key of the region in the HBase web UI. 
It can be done by using TableMapReduceUtil which accepts scan as a parameter. Internally (I think) it call setStartRow and setStopRow to TableInputFormat) 
Here you can find example: 
http://massapi.com/class/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java.html (search for setStartRow in the page).

Comment: Thanks david this is exactly what I was looking for. Here is a small code snippet of how I am doing it.


List<HRegionInfo> tableRegions = admin.getTableRegions(tableName);
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setStartRow(new ImmutableBytesWritable(tableRegions.get(1).getStartKey()).get());
scan.setStopRow(new ImmutableBytesWritable(tableRegions.get(1).getEndKey()).get());  TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(table, scan, AnalyzeMapper.class,


Text.class, IntWritable.class, job); 

.....